# Grid view image link to activites

Tags: java, android

I have hit a brick wall, a tutorial I have followed simply enlarges the images on click.

what I want to do is for each image it opens a different activity.

eg the algebra image open the algebraactivity, decimal image on click opens decimal activity etc.

this is probably simple, but it is not very obvious to me at the moment.

Here is the main activity.

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
import android.widget.GridView;  
public class MathsSubjectsActivity extends Activity {

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.algebraicon,R.drawable.coordsicon,
        R.drawable.decimalsicon,R.drawable.fractionsicon,
        R.drawable.algebraicon,R.drawable.algebraicon,
        R.drawable.powersicon,R.drawable.algebraicon,
        R.drawable.coordsicon,R.drawable.algebraicon,
    }; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.subjects);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view); 
        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class 
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds)); 
 /**      * On Click event for Single Gridview Item      * */  
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MathsAlgebraActivity.class);
                        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(login);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent coords = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MathsMultiActivity.class);
                        coords.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(coords);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent decim = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MathsMultiActivity.class);
                        decim.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(decim);
                        break;
                    //and so on for other activities.
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Below is the image adapter which handles the images.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

private Context mContext;
private Integer[] resIds; 

//Constructor 
public ImageAdapter(Context c,Integer[] resIds){ 
    mContext = c;
    this.resIds=resIds;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {  
    return resIds.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return resIds[position];
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
    imageView.setImageResource(resIds[position]);  
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);   
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70)); 
    return imageView;
}
}
```

can run case 0 but not 1 or 2.

errors from log:

```
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1405    
Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1379  
MathsSubjectsActivity(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 2827  
MathsSubjectsActivity(Activity).startActivity(Intent) line: 2933    
MathsSubjectsActivity$1.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) line: 51  
GridView(AdapterView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 284   
AbsListView$PerformClick.run() line: 1812   
ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 130 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line:     not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: Can you paste the logs for the crash for case 1,2?

Comment: Your logs say that you have not defined the Activity MathsMultiActivity in the Manifest.xml.Do the necessary entry in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

try something like below code

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

         switch(position)
         {
             case 0:
             startActivity(context, FirstActivity.class);
             break;
             case 1:
             startActivity(context, SecondActivity.class);
             break;
             .....
             ...
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1

```
    import android.app.Activity; 
        import android.content.Intent; 
        import android.os.Bundle; 
        import android.view.View; 
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
        import android.widget.GridView;  
        public class MathsSubjectsActivity extends Activity {   

        // Keep all Images in array
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {        
        R.drawable.algebraicon,R.drawable.coordsicon,         
        R.drawable.decimalsicon,R.drawable.fractionsicon,  
        R.drawable.algebraicon,R.drawable.algebraicon,
        R.drawable.powersicon,R.drawable.algebraicon,        
        R.drawable.coordsicon,R.drawable.algebraicon, 
        }; 


         @Override    
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.subjects);  
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view); 
             // Instance of ImageAdapter Class    
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,mThumbIds)); 
             /**      * On Click event for Single Gridview Item      * */  
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  

        @Override         
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {            
         switch(position)             
               {   
                case 0:                 
                   startActivity(this, AlgebraActivity.class);            
                        break;                    
                case 1:                   
                 startActivity(this, CoordsActivity.class);  
                                  break;    

                case 2: 
                startActivity(this,DecimalsActivity.class);
                break;
               //and so on for other activities.  
                default:
                break;                             

 } 


        }     
    }); 
    }   

}
```

And the Adapter would look like :

```
import android.content.Context;   
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.widget.BaseAdapter; 
import android.widget.GridView;  
import android.widget.ImageView;       
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {    
private Context mContext;      
private Integer[] resIds; 
//Constructor 
 public ImageAdapter(Context c,Integer[] resIds){ 
mContext = c;    
this.resIds=resIds
}    
@Override                    
 public int getCount() {  
 return mThumbIds.length;                  
   }         
 @Override                   
public Object getItem(int position) {   
                      return mThumbIds[position];                     }     
  @Override                  
   public long getItemId(int position) {    
                     return 0;                  
   }                                    

      @Override            
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {                                
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
 imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);  
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);   
 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70)); 
 return imageView;                    
 }                                 
  }
```

EDIT 2:

As per the logs it looks there is no entry for the activity in manfest file. Do the following entry for the activity in your androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.example.project.YourActivity"
                  . . . >
            . . .
        </activity>
```

Comment: COuld you show me exactly what you mean in your answer please?

Comment: Changed my answer. Se if that helps.

Comment: wherever mThumbIds is in the imageadapter it is asking to create a local variable?

Comment: change all mThumbIds to resIds in ImageAdapter. Its saying so as now the mThumbIds is part of activity and is no more a global variable in ImageAdapter.

Comment: All the code in the answer is the current code. Still having a problme with case 1 and 2

Comment: can you post the logs for the crash in case 1 & 2?If one case is working every other case should work. I suspect some problem with MathsMultiActivity.